# webmatrix - sql query using DateTime.Now

Tags: sql, datetime, razor, webmatrix

i am trying to write a sql query in Webmatrix to show the count of entries in my database within the last month. I have written the below query, but it's giving me a count of zero, when i know that's not true. I think i may be writing the wrong code to show the last 7 days?

```
var lastweek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
var week =  "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM PropertyViews WHERE PropertyID = @0 AND ViewTimestamp >= @1";
var qweek = db.QueryValue (week, rPropertyId, lastweek);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking at last week, but at the coming week (today + 7 days is in the future!)

Try

```
var lastweek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
```

You mention last month by the way, but i guess you mean week everywhere :)

Comment: works perfectly, thanks so much. I didn't know you could do negative days, which is where i was getting stuck. And yes, i did mean week, not month :p